# Why can't I display data on .cshtml/razor pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm an intern currently learning .NET. I am running an mvc web application in VS17 which displays widgets on a UI and I'm having trouble displaying the application data (taken from a database) onto my UI. My target version for my project is .NET framework 4.6.2. Other applications I'm using include nhibernate and ext.net.

I know my data is being passed through because I can see the data being passed through to data[] when i debug it. Is there any reason why when using Html.X.GridPanel or any html extension, nothing is displayed? The html code is being recognized but gridpanel is not displaying.

Any help is appreciated, I've been at this for weeks.

I've checked web.config in views folder making sure everything is correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODMVm.jpg

cshtml

```
@model Vizor.Models.Load.VisionCameras
@using BackupDataMiner.Domain;
@Html.X().ResourceManager().RenderScripts(ResourceLocationType.None).RenderStyles(ResourceLocationType.None)
@using System.Text;
@using System;

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/extjs/resources/css/ext-all-gray-embedded-css/ext.axd?v=25767" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/extnet/resources/extnet-all-embedded-css/ext.axd?v=25767" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-all-js/ext.axd?v=25767"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extnet/extnet-all-js/ext.axd?v=25767"></script>

@{
if (Model.vCams.Count > 0)
{
object[] data = new object[Model.vCams.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < Model.vCams.Count; i++)
{
BackupDataMiner.Domain.VisionCamera s = Model.vCams[i];
string attName = "";

data[i] = new object[] { s.Model, s.Firmware };
}

@(Html.X().GridPanel()
.BodyStyle("border:0")
.ID(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
.ForceFit(true)
.CellCls("minerlog")
.Scroll(ScrollMode.Vertical).BottomBar(bar => bar.Add(Html.X().PagingToolbar()
.DisplayInfo(true).HideRefresh(true)
.DisplayMsg("Displaying Machines {0} - {1} of {2}")))
.Store(
Html.X().Store().Model(
Html.X().Model().Fields(
new ModelField("Model"),
new ModelField("Firmware"))).DataSource(data).RemoteSort(false).IsPagingStore(true).RemotePaging(true).PageSize(17)
).ColumnModel(

Html.X().Column().Text("Model").DataIndex("Model"),
Html.X().Column().Text("Firmware").DataIndex("Firmware")
)
);
}
else
{
<div>No Vision Cameras Installed on this Machine, or the backup format is old.</div>
}
}
```

controller

```
public class LoadController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult VisionCameras(int MachineID)
  {
    Models.Load.VisionCameras model 
      = new Models.Load.VisionCameras(MachineID);

    return View(model);
  }
}
```

model

```
public class VisionCameras
  {
    private static ILog _logger;
    private static ILog Logger
    {
      get 
      { 
        return _logger 
          ?? (_logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(VisionCameras))); 
      }
    }

public IList<bdm.VisionCamera> vCams = new List<bdm.VisionCamera>();

public VisionCameras(int MachineID)
{ 
try
{
bdm.Machine Machine = DBHandler.Session().Get<bdm.Machine>(MachineID);
IList<BackupDataMiner.Domain.Backup> backups = Machine.Backups.OrderByDescending<BackupDataMiner.Domain.Backup, DateTime>
(x => x.BackupDate).ToList<BackupDataMiner.Domain.Backup>();
bdm.Backup backup = backups.First(x => x.ArchiveName.StartsWith("InVision"));
vCams = backup.VisionCamera; 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
Logger.Debug(e.Message);
}
Logger.Debug("number of Vision cameras: " + vCams.Count);
}
}
}
```

web.config in views

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
<namespaces>
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
<add namespace="Ext.Net" />
<add namespace="Ext.Net.MVC" />
</namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: This question will probably be closed.  Questions look to solve code problem **must include the code in the question itself**.  Otherwise off-site resources may become obsolete and won't help future readers. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Erik, just fixed that.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Razor template with no reference to Html.X.GridPanel and just render a bunch of ul and li's to see whether it works as vanilla MVC? If yes, then you have to ensure the built-in scripts and styles are properly rendered using the built-in RenderScripts/RenderStyles part.

Comment: Yup I've created a new razor template, ul and il's work fine, simple razor code is working too. Just Html.X() etc is not cooperating. How do I ensure the built-in scripts styles are properly rendered? How do i access the built-in RenderScripts/RenderStyles part?